# Can I salvage cookie dough made with whole eggs instead of yolks?

Tags: eggs, cookies

I was making the dough for cookies and was supposed to add just 2 egg yolks and I added 2 whole eggs.  What was supposed to form a ball just made a really thick batter.  So, do I have to start over or is there a way I can fix this?

Recipe called for 4 cups of flour, 2 cups of softened butter, 1 pint of sour cream and 2 egg yolks.  I put in two whole eggs.  It's in the refrigerator chilling in hopes of tightening it up.

They were supposed to be pinwheel cookies that you put a bit of jelly in the center.  And then finish off with powder sugar. If there is no salvaging the consistency of the cookies to form these pinwheels, would it work if I make them into balls and then finish them off with powdered sugar so as to not waste this batch and start over to make the pinwheels with just the yolks?

Answer (score 4):

If nothing else, the egg whites have added additional liquid to your dough, so maybe you can compensate by adding more flour.

Try taking a small portion of your "batter" and add a little flour to it. See if that brings it closer to the consistency you expected. If you can determine how much flour is needed to fix just a small amount of the mix, then you can apply it to the whole thing.

If it doesn't work, you'll still have your Plan-B to fall back on.